# Send Linked IN Message without gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, linkedin-api

I try to send a message to linked in users via several gems, but I get Faraday::Error.

Is there a way to send it without gems? How ?

Iam using ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.1.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can send it using [Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).
- Make sure you have the granted permission for scope `w_messages`

---

#### Here is how to send it:

```
# token : user's token (who is going to send the message)
# subject : Subject of the message
# body : body of the message
# recipient_ids : array of recipient ids (on linkedin) 

require "net/http"

def send_linkedin_message(token, subject, body, recipient_ids)
  path = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/mailbox"
  message = {
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    recipients: {
      values: recipient_ids.map do |profile_path|
        {person: {_path: "/people/#{profile_path}"} }
      end
    }
  }

  uri = URI.parse(path)
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
  request.body = message.to_json
  request.initialize_http_header({ "x-li-format" => "json", "Authorization" => "Bearer #{token}" })
  request.content_type = 'application/json'
  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') {|http| http.request request}
end
```

Comment: did not send the message

Comment: can you add `puts response` to find out what is the error?